# In the performance tab in Firefox dev tools, what does the function 'Tools' refer to?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I'm debugging a performance issue in my app and seeing that Firefox spends a lot of time in Tools. I know what Idle, GC, Network and Gecko refers to but I don't understand what Tools means.
[image: Call tree of a performance recording]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for the Performance panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Performance/Call_Tree#platform_data) *Tools* are part of the platform data. That page unfortunately doesn't explain exactly what "Tools" mean, though. It seems that every page spends some time in "tools" code.

If your page consistently spends most of the time in "Tools", you should expand it by clicking the little arrow besides the word. This will show you one or more functions within your code that take up the time.

Those functions should then get your focus when optimizing your code.